# Call python function from Jquery in Odoo12?

Tags: python, jquery, odoo-12

Ive created a button named `update` in the frontend.

**I need to run the function that I wrote in the python file while clicking the button using jquery**.

**xml**:

```
<t>
<button id="update_health_profile_front" 
        class="btn btn-primary" 
        type="button">Update
</button>
</t>
```

**py**:

```
 @api.multi
    def update_health_profile(self):
        # partner = self.partner_id
        #some_method
```

**js**:

```
$('#update_health_profile_front').click(function(event){
            var rpc = require('web.rpc');
            rpc.query({
            model: 'health.profile',
            method: 'update_health_profile',
        })
        .then(function(result){
            for (i= 0; i< result.length; i++){
                    console.log("result",result[i]);
             }

          },);
```

Its not working and I don't think this is the right way either, Can anybody share some knowledge?

Comment: Well first you didn't specify the framework you're using (django or Flask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can try this, I think it should work.

```
$('#update_health_profile_front').click(function(event){
            var rpc = require('web.rpc');
            rpc.query({
            model: 'this.name',
            method: 'update_health_profile'
        })
        .then(function(result){
            for (i= 0; i< result.length; i++){
                    console.log("result",result[i]);
             }

          },);
```

Comment: BUt an error is coming as follows.

ids, args = args[0], args[1:]
IndexError: list index out of range

And please let me know the use of args in the function

Comment: @Raihan I have made some edits, pls check it out

Comment: @divyesh: i tried to pass the arguments as following ```args: [health_record_id, health_profile_id],```

But one argument is only getting, is there any syntax error here? or can you suggest me some?